# Get rel value from URL link

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml file that has two links in it. I need to check to see if the link with the rel next exists if it does get the href value of it.

```
<a:link rel="prev" type="application/atom+xml" type="application/atom+xml" href="/v3.2/en-us/" />
<a:link rel="next" type="application/atom+xml" type="application/atom+xml" href="/v3.2/en-us/" />
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what you have so far?

Comment: Sorry the most i have gotten is 
string test = ReturnedAppsXml.Element(ns + "link").Attribute(rel).Value;

that returns the value of the first link. How other than looping can I check either with regex or what not if the second link exists with the rel value of next

Comment: That's not valid Xml with two type attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about reading the xml into an XDocument and using LINQ to find the next element.

```
XDocument x = XDocument.Parse("<xml><link rel=\"prev\" type=\"application/atom+xml\" href=\"/v3.2/en-us/\" /> <link rel=\"next\" type=\"application/atom+xml\" href=\"/v3.2/en-us/\" /></xml>");

XElement link = x.Descendants("link")
                 .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("rel").Value == "next");

String href = string.Empty;
if(link != null)
{
     href = link.Attribute("href").Value; 
}
```

Comment: For simplicity I removed the namespace, here is a link to a question about reading xml with namespaces that might come in handy as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996300/search-xml-element-with-xml-namespace-prefix-c-sharp

Comment: This will fail (exception will be thrown) when `.FirstOrDefault` returns the default value of `null` when no value is found for the "rel" attribute.

Comment: Correct, it will throw exceptions if any of the items are missing. I would recommend validating the xml using a schema first.

Comment: Even if it validates, the `FirstOrDefault` will cause an exception if the rel attribute (or value) does not exist; there's no requirement that the value must exist. From the OP: _I need to check to see if the link with the rel next exists if it does get the href value of it._

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this public xml library](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/) and then get the value with:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file); // or .Parse(string)
string href = root.XGetElement<string>("//a:link[@rel={0}]/href", null, "next");
if(null != href)
    ... link was found ...
```

That should work with the `a:link`, but if it doesn't try it without the `a:`.  It would depend on where a's namespace was declared.  If it is in the root node it should be fine.

`XGetElement()` is basically a combination of `XPathElement("//a:link[@rel={0}]").Get<string>("href", null)`. `Get()` also being a part of the library for getting values from nodes, checking first for an attribute by the name and then for a child node.